# Remove navigation bar from a quiz page of moodle

Tags: navigation, moodle

I need modify the quiz page of moodle, I want only the quiz with anythong else. I've got remove all the blocks, but I can`t remove the navigation bar.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have to remove the bit in the theme temlate that does the navigation, which is controlled by this code:

```
$OUTPUT->standard_top_of_body_html();
```

However, the correct way to hook into this is to use the theme engine's page layout mechanism. See the documentation for page layouts [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes#Layouts).

As an example, if you set the page layout to 'popup', it'll remove everything else but the content.

```
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('popup');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use theme css or quiz module css to hide the nav block when in the quiz module:

```
.path-mod-quiz .block_navigation { display:none; }
```

If you want to hide all blocks, then you just make your selectors less specific:

```
.path-mod-quiz .block { display:none; }
```

Just be aware that navigation becomes a bit of a hassle once those blocks are hidden.